# How to Do selection in a widget based on a selection done in a Template widget (JS triggered)

Tags: javascript, widget, iccube, iccube-reporting

in iccube v6 reporting, I have a Template widget called « Map » hereafter that has some code that triggers an event :
Code inside the "Map, Options, `After Render`"  :

```
self.fireEvent(vizEventType.onSelection, new viz.event.SetSelectionEvent(members));
```

[image]

code inside JS, `On Send Event` :

```
function(context, $box, type, args) {
    context.fireEvent("MapZoneSelected",args)
    return args;
}
```

[image]

In the Report JS :

```
function consumeEvent( context, event ) {                                
if (event.name == 'MapZoneSelected') {
    var mapZoneSelected = event.value; // Just used to debug the passed values
} 
}
```

[image]

So, I see the `MapZoneSelected` event is well triggered…

In the Destination widget, `do Set Selection` is defined to `MapZoneSelected`
But the widget doesn’t set it’s selection according to that event… there is a reaction, but it only clears any previous selection.

I can't figure out where I'm wrong...

Comment: It's a template widget, so it's up to the widget to handle multiple selection. Don't see how rebinding the event to the same widget with doSetSelection can help

Comment: What I'm trying to do is "just" set a selection to a widget based on an event from a template widget using name or uniqueName as parameter... Can someone provide a simple working example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created an example report for you with the widget template that sends selection events to the chart widget. Just click on bubbles and you will see selection applied on the chart widget(multisiection supported). You could test it here:

https://demo6.iccube.com/icCube/doc/ic3report?ic3demo=&name=%2Fshared%2FStackOverflow%2FWidget%20Template%20Fire%20Selection&menu=on